# jQuery: How to do I reference a variable from another object

Tags: jquery-ui

Sorry for the mixups. So for the code below, the question is how do I reference a variable object from another object.

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    **title: myPassedVariable,**
    buttons: {
        'Yes': function() {
            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');

            bValid = bValid 

            //&& checkLength(name,"company name",1,16);

            if (bValid) {
                //alert($('#cancel-test').attr("id"));
                //alert(theapptno);
                //alert(document.theform.name);
                //document.theForm.submit() ;                       
                $(this).dialog('close');

            }
        },
        No: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
    }
});

$('.cancel-appt')
    .button()
    .click(function() {
        $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
        **myPassedVariable=this.id;**
    });
```

Comment: You need to add some context to your question

Comment: What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please ask questions more clearly. Posting only your code doesn't really help to know what you've tried or what you want.

That said, it looks like you want to change the title of the dialog form. To do this, you would use the jQuery UI dialog's option function like so:

```
$('.cancel-appt')
.button()
.click(function() {
    $('#dialog-form')
        .dialog( "option", "title", this.id )
        .dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  For a follow up question, I wanted to assign that variable to the code below, instead of passing it from the script.  How can I do that?

> <div class="demo">  <div
> id="dialog-form"
> **title=myPassedVariable**>  <FORM name="theForm" action="#"
> method='POST'>  <fieldset>
>  </fieldset>  </form>  </div> </div>